# Unity - Text object instancing at wrong position

Tags: unity-game-engine, instances

I'm instancing a small UI canvas with text to appear above a pick up on contact:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUpCheck : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject pickUp;
public GameObject textBox;
public GameObject particle;
private Vector3 pickUpPos;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    pickUpPos = pickUp.transform.position;
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    Instantiate(particle, pickUpPos, new Quaternion());
    Instantiate(textBox, pickUpPos , new Quaternion());
    Destroy(pickUp.gameObject);
    }
}
```

The canvas and text appear somewhere else though. Specifically, at the position of the text object I originally reference in the editor.

[image]

I'm not sure why this is overriding the position set in the instance code. I've moved the referenced canvas object prefab around (including to the origin) and re-referenced it to the pick up object and it always will appear at this position instead of the pick up position.

**Edit** - Just to clarify, pickUp is the game object this script is attached to. The GameObject particle is a particle effect set to instance when the object is collided with. It is unrelated to the current problem.

Comment: what are the gameobject pickup and particle in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a simple solution to the problem - I assigned the instance of the created object to a variable and then set the position of that variable to the position of the pick up object:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    pickUpPos = pickUp.transform.position;
    textBox = Instantiate(textBox, pickUpPos , new Quaternion());
    textBox.transform.position = pickUpPos;
    Destroy(pickUp.gameObject);
}
```

Works as intended now.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the position on `Start()` which means that it'll get set once when you start running the game.

Have you tried setting it when you need the current position, like this?

```cs
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    pickUpPos = pickUp.transform.position;
    Instantiate(particle, pickUpPos, new Quaternion());
    Instantiate(textBox, pickUpPos , new Quaternion());
    Destroy(pickUp.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but the canvas object still positions at the referenced object position (position of the canvas object I connect to the script). Also, the pick ups never change position so the position set at start would not differ during runtime.